# Am I using CloseableHttpClient correctly?

Tags: java, performance-testing, apache-httpclient-4.x, latency

Here is how I am using CloseableHttpClient:

```
private static final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(myurl);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

Basically , above code is in a singleton class so only one instance of `httpClient` is present serving all the requests.

Will this be a performance hit that one httpClient is serving all requests?
Because I am seeing slowness in my system when receiving httpResponse.

Also another question I have is do I need to close any of the above resources and if yes then when ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Pooling Connection Manager](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html), as per documentation:

> **PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager** is a more complex implementation that manages a pool of client connections and is able to service connection requests from multiple execution threads. Connections are pooled on a per route basis. A request for a route for which the manager already has a persistent connection available in the pool will be serviced by leasing a connection from the pool rather than creating a brand new connection.

So I would recommend amending your code like:

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
//configure it as per your reqiurements, i.e.
cm.setMaxTotal(5000);
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setConnectionManager(cm)
    .build();
```

Also be aware that there is a free and open source load testing tool called [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) which in particular uses [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) under the hood so you can either use it for your load testing purposes or look into the underlying implementation if you have doubts.

I would recommend reconsidering your approach and use JMeter as when it comes to web applications load testing you need to take care of lots of factors (headers, cookies, cache, authentication, AJAX requests, embedded resources, etc.) and it might require a huge effort to properly implement everything. You can create/run JMeter test via its [API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) from Java code if needed, see [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article for more details.

Comment: Actually the reason for the question was that I was seeing very latency by using default HttpClient.. also the latency is due to requestes taking long time in network even though all components are in same VPN. This was observed while performance testing with jmeter only